# Regex: match a float number in c

Tags: c, regex

I am using the following two regex to match the **numbers**(for example, 1.2, 1 ...)

```
regex_text0 = "[0-9]+|\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]";

regex_text = "[0-9]+|[.][0-9]+|[0-9]+[.][0-9]+";
```

And the following function to execute it.

```
static int match_regex (regex_t * r, const char * to_match)
{
const char * p = to_match;
const int n_matches = 10;
regmatch_t m[n_matches];

while (1) {
    int i = 0;
    int nomatch = regexec (r, p, n_matches, m, 0);
    if (nomatch) {
        printf ("No more matches.\n");
        return nomatch;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n_matches; i++) {
        int start;
        int finish;
        if (m[i].rm_so == -1) {
            printf("break ");
            break;
        }
        start = m[i].rm_so + (p - to_match);
        finish = m[i].rm_eo + (p - to_match);
        if (i == 0) {
            printf ("$& is ");
        }
        else {
            printf ("$%d is ", i);
        }
        printf ("'%.*s' (bytes %d:%d)\n", (finish - start),
            to_match + start, start, finish);
    }
    p += m[0].rm_eo;
}
return 0;
}
```

But the result of two regex are different.

```
Trying to find '[0-9]+|[.][0-9]+|[0-9]+[.][0-9]+' in '1.0 + 2.3'                                                                                
$& is '1.0' (bytes 0:3)                                                                                                                         
break                                                                                                                                           
$& is '2.3' (bytes 6:9)                                                                                                                         
break                                                                                                                                           
No more matches.                                                                                                                                
Trying to find '[0-9]+|.[0-9]+|[0-9]+.[0-9]' in '1.0 + 2.3'                                                                                     
$& is '1.0' (bytes 0:3)                                                                                                                         
break                                                                                                                                           
$& is ' 2' (bytes 5:7)                                                                                                                          
break                                                                                                                                           
$& is '.3' (bytes 7:9)                                                                                                                          
break                                                                                                                                           
No more matches.
```

Question:

- What is the differences in that two regular expression?
- Why the `regexec()` every time just match one number but the prototype of `regexec()` wants an **array of regmatch_t**?

Comment: Unwarranted pro tip: Don't use regexes to parse floating-point numbers, use `strtod` from `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: From your output, you may need to escape the backslash: in the output line "Trying to find ...", there is no backslash, and the '.' becomes the catch-all character (and thus catches the space in front of the 2, ` 2`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your second regex `[0-9]+|[.][0-9]+|[0-9]+[.][0-9]+` allows numbers like `12.21` and `13.131` where the first one only accept `13.1` or `1.1` i.e one digit after `.` if a digit exists before `.`.This is because of the `+` sign at the end of second regex.That is the only differnece between the two regex.